# I see someone verb+s/es or without s/es?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Why did Grammarly correct this sentence below and suggest "make" instead of "makes"?

> **I see her makes a cup of tea.**

Can you explain? I thought it would be "makes" because "her" is there?

Comment: "See" requires a non-finite clause as complement. You can have either an infinitival clause "I see her make a cup of tea", or a gerund-participial clause "I see her making a cup of tea" depending on context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two superficially similar structures:

> I see her make a cup of tea.

> I see [that] she makes a cup of tea.

(I've put "that" in brackets, because it is optional).

So *see* can take *either* an infinitive clause *or* a finite clause.

To my ear, there is a slight difference in meaning: the first says that I see the process; the second says that I see evidence of the fact that she makes the tea: I don't necessarily have to see her doing it to be able to say the second.

Answer (score 2):

The "meat" of your sentence, the subject/verb pair, is **I see**. The verb *to see* is conjugated to agree with the subject *I*.

The rest of the sentence is an object phrase. What do I see? I see *her*. What do I see her do? I see her *make a cup of tea*.

When the verb is part of an object phrase like this, we use the **bare infinitive** form, as [this website](https://performdigi.com/types-of-verbals/) explains:

> An infinitive will almost always begin with ***to***. Exceptions do occur, however. An infinitive will lose it’s [*sic*] ***to*** when it follows verbs like feel, hear, help, let, make, see and watch.
> *The pattern looks like this:*
> special verb + direct object + infinitive – to

Comment: It's best analysed as a catenative construction, where "see" is a catenative verb with the infinitival clause "make a cup of tea" as its catenative complement. The intervening NP "her" is the syntactic object of "see" and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause.

Comment: In other words, clauses can't be objects.

Answer (score 1):

When we perceive an action (see, hear, feel, etc) we may use the base form (infinitive) of the verb for the action.

> I see her **make** a cup of tea.
>
> I heard the choir **sing** in the church.
>
> I felt the house **shake** when the wind blew.

[Hear, see, etc. + object + infinitive or -ing (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing)

We can also use the gerund (-ing) form of the verb (e.g. making, singing, shaking, etc).